# How can I redirect user during login in Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I've added an option for my users to a custom Wordpress page where a user can setup a 2 way authentication for his account. When a user enables the two way authentication I save the generated seed into his user meta. Now I have a problem because I don't know how I can check it during the login process.

I thought it might be a good option to do the normal login first and then check if the user enabled the secure feature. If yes, I could redirect him to a custom page after login where I must enter the verification code. When the code is right I can proceed the login. Is this possible this way? Because when he's already logged in and clicks the account page the user can see the page content so this security feature is then junk and not needed anymore.

Is there someone how knows Wordpress and can help / say me the best hook or place where I can add this verification?

This is not a question about coding my staff! I'll do this all by my own when I know the place and the correct process.

A picture describing my use case:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basic idea is: use session/cookie (choose whichever suits you best) to identify two factor authentication. You can hook them in `init`.

Here is a quick example (not tested, but hope you will get the idea):

```
function twofactor_check () {
    //no need to do anything, if user is not logged in
    if ( !is_user_logged_in() ) {
        return;
    }

    //check two factor
    $two_factor_enabled = 'check if enabled';

    //no headache when two factor is disabled
    if ( !$two_factor_enabled ) {
        return;
    }

    //twofactor is already passed
    if ( isset($_SESSION['two_factor_verified'] ) && $_SESSION['two_factor_verified'] == 'twofactor_passed' ) {
        return;
    }

    if ( session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE ) {
        session_start();
    }

    //twofactor not passed. user will only get landing page.
    if ( !isset($_SESSION['two_factor_verified'] ) ) {
        $_SESSION['two_factor_verified'] = 'started';
        wp_redirect( 'url_to_two_factor_code_landing_page' );
        exit;
    }

    //on your landing page, when passed, set $_SESSION['two_factor_verified'] to 'twofactor_passed'.
    //and when failed, destroy $_SESSION['two_factor_verified'], so user can only access landing page before verifying twofactor.
    //destry $_SESSION['two_factor_verified'], when users log out. you can use 'wp_logout' hook.
}
add_action('init', 'twofactor_check');
```

Comment: I'm back now and I must thank you! Your answer gave me an idea how to do it and now it works like I need it. So thanks m8.

Answer (score 0):

This could solve the problem you have to check if the auth is enabled in this function and redirect the user to your page

```
function admin_default_page() {
  if(auth == 'yes'){
    return '/add-redirect-url-here';
  }

}

add_filter('login_redirect', 'admin_default_page');
```

Comment: This will only work during the login. After reaching landing page, if user types a page url, they will be able to access that page.